# What will be the relation between specific heat of solids and chemical potential?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I found a question which asks: Excitations of a 3 dimensional solid are bosonic in nature. And its angular frequency $w$ is proportional to $K^2$ in the large wavelength limit. If the chemical potential is zero, what will be the specific heat of the solid at low temperature ?

My doubt here is, how does the chemical potential affect the specific heat of the solid at different temperature. that is in this case, if the chemical potential is non zero at a particular temperature (low temp.. in this case), how would be the specific heat of the solid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bosons follow the bose-einstein statistics given by
$$f(E)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left[\beta(E-\mu)\right]}$$
where $\mu$ is the chemical potential. The average energy given by $$\langle E\rangle=\sum Ef(E) $$
and specific heat given by
$$C_V=\frac{d\langle E\rangle }{dT}$$
The dependence is obvious from here.